# Hangs on Splash Screen after login (auto-login), how can I fix this?

Tags: 10.10, installation, login-screen, gdm

Computer: Toshiba Terca A4

OS: Ubuntu Desktop 10.10

After installing 10.10, the splash screen hangs and the mouse pointer appears.

Anyone know what I can do to fix this?

`~/.xsession-errors` has

```
(nautilus:3190): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed
```

btw, Safe-mode works:

I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> into a command prompt session and run

```
ps aux | grep slave
```

then

```
sudo kill [id of gdm-simple-slave]
```

That killed the session and allowed me to login in safe-mode.
Safe-mode works. Then I open a terminal and run

```
ps aux | grep nm-
sudo kill -9 [id of nm-applet]
nm-applet --sm-disable &
```

to get my internet connection up.

Comment: I have the same problem on an Asus 901 Eee PC.  Ctrl-Alt-F1 got me to a console login, but I can not log in for a graphics safe mode.

Comment: man... I am having the exactly same issue... I have tried install many times and still the same thing... really confused what is causing the problem...

Comment: yes i have the same laptop and it does the same thing, its not the disk, and i never made any changes to it. It will only boot on fail safe mode and I would like to fix this because its annoying!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a reinstall and that fixed it for me.

The details are: I did a netbook install -- without mp3 option, without download while installing -- though I suspect that didn't matter and most likely my first install was off a corrupt disk.

btw, Netbook didn't work for me, there were many more errors with that, but using the Ctrl-Alt-F1 technique above got me a new login session, and logging into the regular desktop was a success. Yey!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting nautilus back to its default settings. login on a TTY (CTRL+ALT+F1) and run this:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/nautilus
```

This will undo all custom settings for nautilus but should correct your problem.

Comment: MNiess, Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it and, unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to answer my own question.